# Trouble migrating from graphql-import to just graphql-tools with ApolloServer, directives cease to work

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-tools, graphql-schema

My plight began as a simple desire to expand my graphql schema from a single .graphql file to multiple files so i can better organize the schema and so it wouldn;t grow to one huge file out of control.

My original layout was very straight forward and i had a working schema in a `schema.graphql` file. I would be able to parse it into a string using `importSchema('server/schema.graphql')` from the graphql-import library, which is now deprecated https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-import

They mention that it has been merged into `graphql-tools` in the newest version and provide a migration tutorial here https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/migration-from-import The tutorial seems very straight forward since their first example pretty much illustrate exactly what my code looks like (except i dont use es6 import but old fashoined require):

```
import { importSchema } from 'graphql-import';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';

const typeDefs = importSchema(join(__dirname, 'schema.graphql'));
const resolvers = {
  Query: {...}
};
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
```

And then they say to modify it, simply make these changes

```
import { loadSchemaSync } from '@graphql-tools/load';
import { GraphQLFileLoader } from '@graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader';
import { addResolversToSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';

const schema = loadSchemaSync(join(__dirname, 'schema.graphql'), { loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()] });
const resolvers = { Query: {...} };

const schemaWithResolvers = addResolversToSchema({
  schema,
  resolvers,
});
```

I made those changes but the vital difference is that they no longer use `makeExecutableSchema()` in their example, which is pretty important for me since i need to include the directives. What do i do now with the schema? How do i declare the directives? their documentation for directives still uses `makeExecutableSchema` but i cant use it anymore since the new `loadSchemaSync` function returns an object instead of a string literal which i would need to pass to `typeDefs` in `makeExecutableSchema`

I am using apollo-server, so it seemed a possible workaround was to just declare the directives in the apollo-server constructor and just pass in this new `schemaWithResolvers` as a schema as such

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema, //this includes now the returned value of using addResolversToSchema()
    schemaDirectives : {
        auth:AuthDirective,
        authRole: AuthRoleDirective
    }
    context : ({req}) => //dostuff,

});
```

This allows my server to run, and i can perform queries and mutations, however, my directives are no longer working, and i no longer have authentication on protected queries.

I would like a way to import my .graphql file and parse it into a string so i can use it inside `typeDefs` as i used to with importSchema() or a way to declase my directies without using makeExecutableSchema() so that they continue working again!

I have gone up and down the documentation and seen other libraries and so far i keep coming up short, any tips or guidance is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`makeExecutableSchema` is still part of `graphql-tools` and you can continue to use it as shown [here](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/generate-schema) in the docs. The issue with the example shown in the docs is that it's not equivalent to what you were doing before. You should use `loadTypedefsSync` instead:

```
import { loadTypedefsSync } from '@graphql-tools/load';
import { GraphQLFileLoader } from '@graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader';
import { addResolversToSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';

const sources = loadTypedefsSync(join(__dirname, 'schema.graphql'), { loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()] });
const documentNodes = sources.map(source => source.document);
const resolvers = { Query: {...} };

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });
```

Alternatively, if you go the `loadSchema` route, you should be able to apply the directives to your schema after loading it:

```
import { SchemaDirectiveVisitor } from "@graphql-tools/utils";
import { loadSchemaSync } from '@graphql-tools/load';
import { GraphQLFileLoader } from '@graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader';
import { addResolversToSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';

const schema = loadSchemaSync(join(__dirname, 'schema.graphql'), { loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()] });
const resolvers = { Query: {...} };

const schemaWithResolvers = addResolversToSchema({
  schema,
  resolvers,
});

SchemaDirectiveVisitor.visitSchemaDirectives(schemaWithResolvers, schemaDirectives);
```

Comment: i cannot find loadTypedefsSync in the documentation anywhere, so not sure how you know about it but thanks! this solution worked for me!

Comment: So both solutions worked for me, so thanks, however, the first solution using loadTypedefsSync did not allow me to import multiple .graphql files and use the #import feature within the files, but the second approach did. Do you have an approach for using your first solution but still being able to import multiple `.graphql` files and use the #import feature within the files?

Comment: `loadSchema` uses `loadTypedefs` under the hood, so I would expect the behavior to be same with regard to the import syntax. You may want to open an issue against the repo with that question

Comment: how do you find out about these functions? loadTypedefs i cannot find in the documentation for graphql-tools and the repo for graphql-tools/load gave me a 404, do you straight up look at the source code?

Comment: If anyone tripped up trying solution #1 going from documentNodes to typeDefs, you need to import { concatAST } from "graphql" and then typeDefs = concatAST(documentNodes)

Comment: So far I haven't used _makeExcecutableSchema_ since it seems I could avoid it. Here's my tweak to get Apollo running: **typeDefs = sources.map(source => source.document); new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers, ... })**

Comment: `documentNodes` in the first solution should be `typeDefs`

Comment: When using the second approach, how do I create schemaDirectives var from a DocumentNode object containing the directive declarations?

Comment: In the first example you aren't even including the schema directives.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this way but I couldn't solve the problem. A unique solution that managed to take the following approach:

```
const { ApolloServer, makeExecutableSchema, gql} = require('apollo-server-express')
const { loadTypedefsSync }  = require('@graphql-tools/load')
const { GraphQLFileLoader } = require('@graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader')
const path = require('path')

const sources = loadTypedefsSync(
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../schema/root.graphql'),
    { loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()] }
)
const typeDefs = sources.map(source => source.document)
```

```
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: gql`${typeDefs[0]}`,
    resolvers,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I loaded the Schema via `.graphql` and I want to add the [graphql-constraint-directive](https://github.com/confuser/graphql-constraint-directive). My Solution was to load the schema with `loadSchemaSync` and then to use the `wrapSchema` to use the transform functions, you need also to add the directives into one of your `.graphql` files:

```
import { addResolversToSchema, wrapSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';
import resolvers from './resolver';

schema = loadSchemaSync('./**/*.graphql', {
  loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()],
});

const schemaWithResolver = addResolversToSchema({
    schema,
    resolvers
  });

const { constraintDirective } = require('graphql-constraint-directive')
  
const schemaConstrain = wrapSchema({
  schema: schemaWithResolver,
  transforms: [constraintDirective()]
})
```

[Documentation to Schema Wrapping](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/schema-wrapping)

Comment: You don't need to use wrapSchema. It is not ideal. It adds an additional delegation step which might have performance implications please follow graphql-constraint-directive docs for this. We don't use wrapSchema in any of examples about directives in GraphQL Tools documentation.